# Why app.param not work if I specify a router.param in Express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

All:

I am pretty new to Express.js, when I tried .param(), one interesting thing is:

In app.js ( the main server file), I have something like:

```
app.param("id", function(req, res, next, id){
  console.log(id+" in app level");
  next();
})
app.use("/", routes);
```

The app is the Express Application object, and in routes Router module:

```
router.param("id", function(req, res, next, id){
    console.log(id + " in router level");
    next();
})

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

But when I request /testUserId, only the param() inside the router module runs, I thought app.param() will run first then router.param(), but it is actually not, could anyone help explain why( I must miss some parts of the API document from Express ) and how to make both run?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I agree that this is somewhat confusing. There was conversation about this, and issue was opened to clarify this behavior in documentation ([Explain that .param doesn't get inherited in mounted routers.](https://github.com/strongloop/expressjs.com/issues/159)).

Here is latest explanation: 
[app.param([name], callback)](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param)

> Param callback functions are local to the router on which they are
>   defined. They are not inherited by mounted apps or routers. Hence,
>   param callbacks defined on app will be triggered only by route
>   parameters defined on app routes.

To recap, behavior that you see is expected. Nested 'routers' or 'apps' do not inherit `.param()` from parent app.